# SOAP Server in JAVA <-> SOAP Client in C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with a SOAP Server written in JAVA, the project is running as a windows service and not as a webserver (e.g. GLASSFISH).
So the problem is, everytime I make a request from a C# .NET client, the JAVA SOAP server is not able to parse the request. The called function gets a NULL value as input parameter.

The communictaion with JAVA clients, SoapUI, aso. works perfectly but the .NET (C#) clients are sending maleformed requests I think. Because the project is already existing and installed a lot of times, I can't develope it in C#. 
I've read a lot of threads with similar problems, but I couldn't find any solution for my case.

I just wrote some simple test cases to show you the problem in a short way.

**JAVA Code:**

```
main.java
//...
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new WS());
endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8081/test"); 
//...

WS.java
//...
@WebService(serviceName = "WS")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class WS {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "echo")
    public String echo(@WebParam(name = "val") String val) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

**The WSDL:**

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webj/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webj/" name="WS">
<types/>
<message name="echo">
    <part name="val" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="echoResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="WS">
    <operation name="echo">
        <input wsam:Action="http://webj/WS/echoRequest" message="tns:echo"/>
        <output wsam:Action="http://webj/WS/echoResponse" message="tns:echoResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WSPortBinding" type="tns:WS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <operation name="echo">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://webj/"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://webj/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="WS">
    <port name="WSPort" binding="tns:WSPortBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://xxx:8081/test"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

**C# Request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <s:Body>
        <echo xmlns="http://webj/">
            <val xmlns="http://webj/">TEST</val>
        </echo>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**JAVA Request**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:std="http://webj/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <std:echo>
            <val>TEST</val>
        </std:echo>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The problem seems to be the namespave of the parameter "val":

```
 <echo xmlns="http://webj/">
   <val xmlns="http://webj/">TEST</val>
 </echo>
```

I've already tested this case in JAVA by adding a namespace to the parameter "val" manually and got the same problem. In C# I've tried with generated WebReferences and ServiceReferences.

(e.g. ServiceReference)

```
TestService.WSClient proxy = new TestService.WSClient();
String results = proxy.echo("TEST");
```

Can someone tell me how I can get the JAVA server compatible for .NET requests please?
Thanks for help!

Comment: use SoapUI as mockup server and see for yourself what is your C# code sending.

Comment: @ JIV C# is sending the above "C# Request" (i've logged the transmission on the JAVA side)

Comment: And is that request from C# valid in SoapUI?

Comment: No, the C# request fails too when sent from SoapUI. But if I send the C# request from .NET Application to a SoapUI mock service, created from the java wsdl, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Java JDK 1.8?
Because I don't think C# .NET is sending the namespace for the parameter, but it's sending an empty namespace like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <s:Body>
        <echo xmlns="http://webj/">
            <val xmlns="">TEST</val>
        </echo>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Java JDK 1.8 contains a JAX-WS version with a bug. The empty namespaces of the requests of your C# client will be parsed completely wrong, just like your C# example above.

Try using the newsest version of [>JAX-WS<](https://jax-ws.java.net/).

[>Here<](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) you can find the description how to implement the libs.

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my weekend!
The issue comes from the java version, I've tested with JDK 6&7 without any problems. After that I've included the new jax-ws version with the vmoptions and it worked perfectly!
It seems that java is manipulating the incoming messages before I've logged them...

Answer (score 0):

As I see You have problem in namespaces, So when java parses it, finds no value and that's why you get null in Object values. Try to get the same XML structures from C#

Comment: Thanks for the response!
But that leads to my next question, how can I edit the XML structure of a WebReference in C#...

Comment: I don't exactly know how it works in C#. For example in Java there is used @Annotation to get the namespace as you want. Try to find the same thing in C#.